# How to force eclipse to use the SceneBuilder executable file? Mac os x

Tags: eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to get SceneBuilder to work with `Eclipse v4.4.2` on Mac OS X. I'm following the advice from this tutorial: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/. I downloaded the Mac OS .dmg version of the SceneBuilder app from here: http://gluonhq.com/products/downloads/. It works when I run it as a stand alone.

When I try to configure Eclipse to use the app as part of the `e(fx)eclipse` package, Eclipse seems to be configured to look for the file `Contents/MacOs/scenebuilder-launcher.sh` in the application package contents. The version of the app I have doesn't have it, instead it just has the executable `Contents/MacOs/SceneBuilder`.

> Failure to launch SceneBuilder [...] Cannot run program "/Applications/SceneBuilder.app/Contents/MacOs/scenebuilder-launcher.sh". No such file or directory.

Does anyone know which version of SceneBuilder I should be using (and where I can get it), or is there a hacky solution to sort this?

Just playing around with the SceneBuilder standalone it seems like it's a **big** step up from WindowBuilder, shame that just finding a packaged/compiled version of it has been so difficult!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer provided by ItachiUchiha is not the full solution with the new binaries provided by Gluon. Obviously they have forgotten to package the file Contents/MacOs/scenebuilder-launcher.sh with the new binaries. It is however sufficient to just copy over this file from an old version of SceneBuilder to make the launch from within Eclipse work.

Comment: Do you know where I can find an old version the app? Or alternatively could you post the contents of the .sh script?

Comment: The Oracle archive is here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html Use the 2.0 version.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. I created an issue: https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/24/eclipse-macos-doesnt-start-scenebuilder and we'll fix this soon!

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys my solution is not clean by the way I use:

On OSX :

```
$cd /Applications/SceneBuilder.app/Contents/MacOS/
$ln -s  SceneBuilder  scenebuilder-launcher.sh
```

And for that works.

Answer (score 1):

**On a Mac:

I just installed sceneBuilder 8.3.**

After setting up Eclipse with the proper SceneBuilder executable (in the Applications folder)

I had the same problem.

Failure to launch SceneBuilder [...] Cannot run program "/Applications/SceneBuilder.app/Contents/MacOs/scenebuilder-launcher.sh". No such file or directory.Error=2

Then **in Eclipse** I went to the 
**Help Menu**, **Check for Updates** *and* **Installed 
all of the latest updates offered**.

When **I was asked if OK to Re-Start Eclipse** I clicked **OK**.

After Eclipse restart 
I Right Clicked on a **Main.fxml** and selected 
**Open with SceneBuilder**.

It worked perfectly.

Best of Luck to you all

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path in

```
Eclipse -> Preference -> JavaFX -> SceneBuilder Executable
```

[image]

Comment: I've already done that, the problem is Eclipse always appends `/contents/macos/scenebuilder-launcer.sh` to the directory provided. The version of the app I have doesn't have the script.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on my mac following the code.makery tutorial but discovered you can still use the official JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 download from oracle.com available at [JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html).

After downloading and installing (by double-clicking on the downloaded .dmg file and dragging to the application folder), simply navigate to Eclipse>preferences>JavaFX and then browse to your Applications folder and select the `JavaFX Scene Builder` app you just installed. Worked and is still working for me!

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to use an old, outdated and unsupported piece of software?

Comment: I chose this method because it is simple, it worked at the time and it is for educational purposes. If I gain more insight with more recent piece of software, i shall make same known. Of course feel free to post your up-to-date solution and I will acknowledge your answer.

Comment: I concur the Gluon is the most-up-to date version. I have not had much experience modifying *.sh files, so I went with the "legacy" Oracle offering. It would be a huge help if you could update your answer to show how this `scenebuilder-launcher.sh` file could be copied.

Comment: I do not understand what your problem is. If you have currently installed the Oracle version, then just go to your program folder, right-click on the SceneBuilder.app and show the package content. Then copy the file /contents/macos/scenebuilder-launcer.sh somewhere. After that you just install the Gluon version and after that is done copy the saved file back into that same location. That's it. You don't have to modify the file but you may need administrator rights to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the older version of scene builder from oracle site. Copied the scenebuilder-launcher.sh from the fresh installation directory to the Glueon scenebuilder directory. And this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution on Mac OSX was gleaned from the bug report at https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/issues/2. Apparently newer versions of Scene Builder (not including version 2 and before) are missing the scenebuilder-launcher.sh file. To make this all work, do the following.

1. Install a new version of Scene Builder from Gluon (not Oracle). I used https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/. Install AND OPEN Scene Builder. For this to work, it is important to actually open Scene Builder before attempting to use it in Eclipse. If you don't, the first invocation under Eclipse will attempt to pop up a the normal OSX security message which, of course, it can't do because it is being invoked from a shell script. This only happens on first invocation, so the next time you won't have the problem. You get a message to the effect that the application is damaged. You will also get this message if you install a new version. Just invoke the Scene Builder application standalone before continuing to use it with Eclipse.
2. open a terminal session (sorry I don't know of another way to do this otherwise as you need to make the file you create executable)
3. cd /Applications/SceneBuilder.app/Contents/MacOS
4. sudo vi scenebuilder.sh (or use your favorite editor other than vi)
5. cut-and-paste the file from the Gluon issue into your editor and save it.
6. sudo chmod +x scenebuilder.sh
7. open Eclipse and open Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations (or type file in the filter box and select File Associations.
8. scroll down to .fxml in the file type box and select it. If you don't see it, click add  to the right of the file types list. Enter .fxml and click OK.
9. in the associations pane, click Add to the right of the associations pane and click the Internal radio button. Scroll down to Scene Builder and select it. Click OK, the Apply and Close.

You should now be able to right-click on an .fxml file and click Open with Scene Builder and Scene Builder should start with the fxml file open in the builder.